# Rendering on Android website Symfony 2 and twig

Tags: android, html, symfony, twig

I have this code :

```
public function headerAction($activeRoute)
{
    $activeRouteArray = explode('_', $activeRoute);

    return $this->render('FrontendBundle::header.html.twig',
        array('activeController' => @$activeRouteArray[1], 'mainmenu' => $menu )
    );
}
```

- $menu is a string that contains a Top Bar, link: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

header.html.twig:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
   <section class="top-bar-section">
     <ul class="left">{{mainmenu|raw}}</ul>
     <ul class="right">
       <li class="divider"></li>
     </ul>
   </section>
</nav>
```

- On desktop, laptop everything are OK, BUT on mobile SIII, mozzila browser It's displayed only the first button from menu. (I have more than one button.).

on layout.html.twig:

```
`<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 </head>`
```

What I should do?

Comment: and its not the normal responsive behaviour of the foundation topbar?

Comment: with ..<meta name="viewport" .../> should be responsive ...but i deleted the meta tag and is working.

Answer (score 0):

if the screen is small "meta" tag  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` it's hiding the menu --so I deleted.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon" style="width:auto"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">{{mainmenu|raw}}</ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

But on my code I have : `<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon" style="width:auto"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>` on small screen this should be displayed ...and didn't work :(.